# How would you execute this on VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-8

I've found the following code online but don't know how to run it on IDE as I'm new to Java could you please help.

```
class Figure {
  void display() { System.out.print("Figure "); }
}
class Rectangle extends Figure {
  void display() { System.out.print("Rectangle "); }
  void display(String s){ System.out.print(s); } 
}
class Box extends Figure {
  void display() { System.out.print("Box ");  }
  void display(String s){ System.out.print(s); }
} 

Figure f = new Figure();
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
Box b = new Box();
f = r;
((Figure) f).display();
f = (Figure) b;
f.display();
```

I tried creating a class and copy-pasting the code but couldn't manage to produce any output. Super stuck and am still a novice. Doing it by hand I think it should output Rectangle Box.

Comment: you probably will want the "Extension pack for java" as it will help you run/setup a basic project.  Also how are you currently running the code? are you using `java` and `javac` for compiling and running?

Comment: Here: https://code.labstack.com/uMC0YAAu

Comment: Since i'm on VSCode I was just pressing run at the top. Ashu's answer seems to work. I need to explore now how to properly set up projects and the purpose of the main class. Thanks

Comment: @LevinKent a class with the static main method is the entry point to a project (or other classes in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Figure.java:**

```
class Figure {
  void display() { System.out.print("Figure "); }
}
```

**Rectangle.java:**

```
class Rectangle extends Figure {
  void display() { System.out.print("Rectangle "); }
  void display(String s){ System.out.print(s); } 
}
```

**Box.java:**

```
class Box extends Figure {
  void display() { System.out.print("Box ");  }
  void display(String s){ System.out.print(s); }
}
```

The rest code should be in `main` method and you can put `main` method in any one of the above .java files. I put it in `Figure.java`, please have a try.

[image]